# How can I get a Ajax-Response without knowing the Request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to have the Response on Ajax-Requests made by the Webpage I'm in, but I have no access to the Request.
Reason: The request is stored in a local variable and I can't change the code where the variable is available (because of update-issues).
The request is sent via XMLHttpRequest (and NOT jquery :-( ).

I know, this all sounds like im producing crap-code, but it's all on customer-wishes :-/

Comment: Is the local variable the XMLHttpRequest object?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know more of what is happening here- how is your code invoked? It seems quite improbable that you would be unable to access another variable on the same page if you really wanted to, even if you had to walk the DOM from the root of the page to find it.

Comment: Jack: Yes.
glenatron: I would be glad if there is an eventing-way, so that the Response invokes my code.
I don't understand how I could walk the DOM to find a local Javascript var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have it resolved:
It is not possible. Without access to the XHR-Object there is no possibility to get knowledge of it.
jQuery saves the XHR globally, so they can provide global event handlers.